# How to handle content type azip and content encoding application/a-gzip in GoLang?

Tags: go, curl, httprequest, app-store-connect

I am trying to use App Store Connect API to download finance and sales reports using GoLang.

I successfully connected a call to App Store API server and receiving the correct output.

By i am not able to download that reports as they are sending the response in bytes with the content type "azip".

Below is my Go Code:

```
url := "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports?filter[frequency]=DAILY&filter[reportType]=SUBSCRIPTION_EVENT&filter[reportSubType]=SUMMARY&filter[vendorNumber]=87389901&filter[reportDate]=2018-10-12&filter[version]=1_1"

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjZROUM1WVc0N1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiI2OWE2ZGU5MC00NGNiLTQ3ZTMtZTA1My01YjhjN2MxMWE0ZDEiLCJleHAiOjE1NDIyNzM0MzcsImF1ZCI6ImFwcHN0b3JlY29ubmVjdC12MSJ9.fC4zmgaUZZTwtopt9gaSl6HUtACNjBvWi5VNa366d5FI5l_00wM1U2cBi26a0jtB8yuZOufDSQA0MB5iMC332g")

res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

fmt.Println(res.Header.Get("Content-Encoding"))

defer res.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

fmt.Println(res)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

Below are the headers what i am getting.

```
Server = daiquiri/3.0.0
Date  = Thu, 15 Nov 2018 12:01:47 GMT
Content-Type = application/a-gzip
Transfer-Encoding = chunked
Connection  = keep-alive
requestId = 24e0c473-a35f-4374-846c-d17007c49978
Content-Encoding = agzip
Content-Disposition → attachment;filename = Subscription_Event_87389901_20181012_V1_1.txt.gz
x-reports-filename = Subscription_Event_87389901_20181012_V1_1.txt.gz
x-reports-download-version = 1_1
Strict-Transport-Security = max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-XSS-Protection = 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff
Host = reportingitc-reporter-internal.corp.apple.com
X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-ID = QSBM3FPCNVUODU2H5FCQRL5T
X-Rate-Limit = user-hour-lim:3600;user-hour-rem:3599;
x-daiquiri-instance = daiquiri:38493001:pv50p00it-hyhk12043901:13987:18O38
```

It may be possible i am doing something wrong. But please let me know how can i store this as a file using GoLang.

Comment: This is probably just gzip data. Try to unzip it. (And please do not post images)

Comment: Try to avoid posting image if possible. In this case you can type the headers instead of posting image

Comment: thanks i have removed image

Comment: @Volker i don't think so it is only a gzip data, when i make a request using postman, it gives me download button and when i click on download then it will download the .gz file.

Comment: But what is it. Did you try to unzip it? Did you run file on it? Are you sending the same headers as Postman? Did you set Accept header?

Comment: I really hope that auth token isn't real. If it is, you should make sure it's revoked (editing it out of the question is not sufficient, it's already compromised by posting it).

Comment: Hey Anam, 
Why did you end up doing? I am running into the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need add parameter Accept in header with "application/a-gzip" value

Example:

```
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/salesReports", nil)
request.Header.Add("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %v", token.Bearer))
request.Header.Add("Accept", "application/a-gzip")
```